# jQuery solution for paging through thumbnails before posting ~ to Facebook

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, thumbnails

Does anyone have suggestions how to do this?

I have an array in my view with the image URLs, like

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/CRIME/06/18/florida.casey.anthony.trial/t1main.anthony.os.jpg
    [1] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/images/06/18/c1main.black.hole.nasa.cxc.jpg
    [2] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/LIVING/06/16/texas.veterans.legacy/tzvids.price.courtesy.jpg
    [3] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/LIVING/06/18/pet.road.trips.rs/tzvids.pet.road.trip.jpg
    [4] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/SHOWBIZ/06/17/photos.reynolds.auction/tzvids.monroe.dress.nca.jpg
    [5] => http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/images/06/18/tzvids.grill.cnn.jpg
)
```

I wonder if there is a jQuery plugin that would allow me to mimic FB's functionality in which one can page through the thumbnails, and when submitting the currently active image is saved with the post.

Any suggestions -- even a partial solution or roadmap -- are greatly appreciated.

_

[image]

Comment: "Submitted with the post"... generic form post or posted to Facebook?

Comment: @niklas - in fact it would be generic form post, since the post is originally posted on my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always take into account the fact that not all of your users may have JavaScript enabled. To accomodate those users, you should try and build your applications in a way that there is always some sort of HTML fallback there to serve the users who may have JS disabled or not available.

One approach with `noscript` fallback as well as the ability to send the data in a form:

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/5cnxh/

Comment: this is a very nice fiddle, thank you! do you have any suggestion on how to present the thumbs cropped to a specific dimension? I thought of TimThumb but that would require storing images as temp -- any client-side solution for cropping or should I go server-side? I see server-side sort of wasted resources since only 1 thumb will be chosen/saved.

Comment: @torr You can with CSS set predefined dimensions, or if you actually want to do cropping, you could place them inside a div with overflow hidden or as background-images (second option would only work properly with JS enabled)

Comment: the CSS/overflow solution works perfectly - thx for your help

Answer (score 1):

There are two options: do it yourself, or use a plugin.

This is basically an image carousel, so jcarousel or similar would work. Just give it no transition and show one image at a time.

To do it directly, stack all the image elements on top of each other with CSS absolute positioning. Either hide all but one, or give the active on higher Z-index. Bind next/prev to cycle through which one is visible.

Comment: +1 for the roadmap - any suggestions how to grab the active and send its URL on submit?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/9vjyP/. I think it is rather self-explanatory.

```
var current = 0;

var arr = [
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/CRIME/06/18/florida.casey.anthony.trial/t1main.anthony.os.jpg',
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/images/06/18/c1main.black.hole.nasa.cxc.jpg',
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/LIVING/06/16/texas.veterans.legacy/tzvids.price.courtesy.jpg',
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/LIVING/06/18/pet.road.trips.rs/tzvids.pet.road.trip.jpg',
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/SHOWBIZ/06/17/photos.reynolds.auction/tzvids.monroe.dress.nca.jpg',
'http://i2.cdn.turner.com/cnn/2011/images/06/18/tzvids.grill.cnn.jpg'
];

$('#prev').click(function() {
    $('img').attr('src', arr[--current]);
    return false;
});

$('#next').click(function() {
    $('img').attr('src', arr[++current]);
    return false;
});

$('#submit').click(function() {
    alert($('img').attr('src'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: That's a good start, it just needs a way to handle current going below zero or above arr.length.

Comment: @ pimvdb thanks for the great fiddle - will try this one if I have trouble implementing @niklas' solution